# AWS CloudFormation: Resource handler returned message: "The CIDR '10.240.20.128/25' conflicts with another subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I have created a subnet Az1 Sync Subnet (10.240.20.128/25) and deployed it.
Now I am trying to change the name of the subnet from "Sync" to "HA" subnet - "Az1 HA Subnet"

So i changed the name of the subnet

Mappings:
VPCaddressPrefix:
values:
vpcOctet: '10.240'

**Before:**  (This code is already successfully deployed and a subnet exists in AWS )

Az1SyncSubnet:
Properties:
AvailabilityZone: !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,AvailabilityZone1 ]
CidrBlock: !Join
- .
- - !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,vpcOctet ]
- '20'
- 128/25
Tags:
- Key: Name
Value: Az1 SyncSubnet
- Key: Owner
Value: !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,Owner ]
VpcId: !Ref Vpc
Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'

**After change:**
Az1HASubnet:
Properties:
AvailabilityZone: !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,AvailabilityZone1 ]
CidrBlock: !Join
- .
- - !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,vpcOctet ]
- '20'
- 128/25
Tags:
- Key: Name
Value: Az1 HA Subnet
- Key: Owner
Value: !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,Owner ]
VpcId: !Ref Vpc
Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'

But getting error as
"Az1HASubnet - CREATE_FAILED: Resource handler returned message: "The CIDR '10.240.20.128/25' conflicts with another subnet (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 788f2216-1f79-4596-8430-7d45e8bbee1c)" (RequestToken: f3a4525d-3f44-5273-196a-764012876a33, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)

Is it not possible to change the name of subnet after deployed ? Any work around hwo to change the name of the subnet ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the logical ID of the resource in CloudFormation. That is not possible, as CloudFormation does not know that the old resource is the same as the new resource. When it sees this update, it believes you simultaneously added a new subnet with the new name while deleting the old one.

The error is happening because CloudFormation is trying to create a new subnet with the existing configuration, thus the conflicting CIDR. (It is trying to add the newly discovered Subnet before deleting the old one.)

If you really want to define a new logical ID for a CloudFormation resource, you must do the following:

1. Set the [DeletionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) to `Retain` the resource upon deletion.
2. Next, remove the resource from the stack. (It will **not** be deleted in your AWS environment due to the DeletionPolicy.)
3. [Import the existing resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) into your CloudFormation stack with the desired logical ID.